# How to identify and copy the most recently added files in Azure Data Factory when there are multiple sub-folders?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

The way folders are structured in DF is something like this:

Parentfolder/Subfolder1/Subfolder12/Subfolder13/File1
Parentfolder/Subfolder2/Subfolder22/Subfolder23/File2
Parentfolder/Subfolder3/Subfolder32/Subfolder33/File3

The Goal is create a pipeline that can identify the file that was most recently added under the Parentfolder and copy only that file and move to Sink. This may require multiple nested pipelines & foreach loops but I have not been able to get to a solution.

Comment: I think azure DevOps can help you here. You must have set up azure DevOps behind ADF Pipeline. If any changes are committed to the pipeline those are logged at DevOps. There onwards you can use the DevOps pipeline to trigger some azure function to get the latest files added or changes. I have not used trigger but this should work out.

Answer (score 0):

In order to copy the last modified file from a folder you can follow the steps described in this thread - [ADF: copy last modified blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/349584/index.html)

If you are having multiple subfolders under a parent folder and you want to copy the latest file from each subfolder, then you will have to use a parent pipeline in which you use GetMetaData activity to get the list of subfolders and then pass the output to a subsequent ForEach activity to iterate through the list of sub folder names and then inside ForEach activity have an Execute pipeline activity which will execute the [copy the last modified](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/349584/index.html) pipeline for each subfolder.

Below GIF is just to copy last modified file from a folder:

[image]

This topic is being discussed here as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/379892/index.html